# SOQL to determine if parent has child records

Tags: soql, parent, childrelationship

Simple and short question, what is the cheapest way to query (plain SOQL) if an object has child records? I want to avoid running into limits even if there are parents with millions of child records.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join) to get the data you want with pure SOQL. For example:

```
SELECT Id FROM Parent__c WHERE Id IN (SELECT Parent__c FROM Child__c)
```

The joined rows do not count against your query row limit.

Answer (score 2):

e.g.

```
for(Account acc:[Select Id, (Select Id From Contacts limit 1) From Account Where Id=:idVar]) {
         if(acc.Contacts != null && acc.Contacts.size() >0) {
             System.debug('Has child records.');
         } else {
             System.debug('No child records.');
         }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and how would this work with plain SOQL? (Without Apex) I updated the question to make that clear.

Comment: @TarifAbuZara `[Select Id, (Select Id From Contacts limit 1) From Account Where Id=:idVar]` is the query. `:idVar` is just there to fetch a single Account.

Comment: @TarifAbuZara, if you are looking for only SOQL query without if-else then i am afraid you could do through SOQL which is possible through other RDBMS e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018757/simple-sql-to-check-if-parent-has-any-child-rows-or-not